# If in .htaccess I block php errors from showing, will the customer error handler still work?

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

I have learned that you can prevent php errors from appearing in the browser using .htaccess. If I do so, will a custom error handler I have set with set_error_handler still work or will that be blocked too?

Something like:

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your custom error handler is still called.

However, you should be aware of the restrictions of a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php):

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.
>
> If errors occur before the script is executed (e.g. on file uploads) the custom error handler cannot be called since it is not registered at that time.